# Razor view stops working after encapsulating attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

So I have this C# MVC project with some views in Razor.

If I change an existing field in my model to a property or vice-versa, any Razor view that references this field stops working and I get a System.MissingFieldException at run time, even though the field is still there. The view only works again if I make any change to it e.g. adding a blank space somewhere. For Example,

If I change this:

```
public class Test
{
   public List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
}
```

To This:

```
public class Test
{
    private List<string> _myStrings = new List<string>();

    public List<string> myStrings
    {
        get
        {
            return _myStrings;
        }
        set
        {
            _myStrings = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to have the views refreshed automatically so I don't have to find every view that references that property and make changes to the view?

Comment: Did you change the view too? _myStrings was public and accessible to the views, after changing it to private, it will no longer be available to the views. In the views you need to use myStrings

Comment: The view was accessing myStrings, it just now has a backing field?

Comment: Your view needs recompilation I guess? Since property gets are actually method calls (vs field access)

Comment: Have you tried turning the MvcBuildViews setting on for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Test` class located in a different project/class library. **Rebuild you solution** once, because [Changing a field into a property is a breaking change (MSDN)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2006/04/11/changing-a-field-to-a-property/). The Compiler will not throw an error upon changing a field to a property, because a `property` is used with the same syntax as a `field`. But internally they are different things. Different types of `MSIL` signature are generated for properties and fields (go through the first link). Property gets called from the client as a method call.

This chapter on [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx) from Jon Skeet's *"C# in Depth"* book is also worth a read.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. We believe the problem has to do with the CMS (Orchard) that sits on top of the application. As a temporary solution we added a code which looks through all the .csthml files in the solution and adds a blank space at the end of the file. That forces to check-out the files and it works after doing that.